# Relying on PR_DISPLAY_NAME property for "SMS" and "ActiveSync" named message stores

Tags: windows-mobile, mapi

I'm trying to find out the type of message store on windows mobile devices (version 6.1 & 6.5).

More specifically I'm trying to figure out if a message store is of type "Exchange (ActiveSync)" and NOT SMS or other E-Mail account type (POP3, IMAP etc).

I'm relying on the fact that the value returned for property `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` for SMS Store is `"SMS"` and for Exchange Store is `"ActiveSync"`.

**My question is**, can I rely on these values to determine the message-store type? Is there a better way to achieve this?

**Following is the pseudo-code depicting my logic:**

```
 bool isActiveSyncSet = areAnySyncAccountSet(); // I use Sync configuration service
                                                // provider to check if any ActiveSync accounts are set.

// Initialize MAPI and fetch all stores
while(we_have_stores) {

    // Open Current Store
    openCurrentStore(&currentStore);

    string storeName = fetchStoreName(currentStore); // using GetProps method fetch PR_DISPLAY_NAME

    if(storeName == "SMS" ) continue;
    if(isActiveSyncSet && storeName == "ActiveSync") {
          // We got the Exchange Message Store
          break;
    } else {
          // We have an E-Mail store but not an ActiveSync one
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of offline research and testing the string returned on lots of different devices[1], I've come to the conclusion that:

**One can rely** on the string `"ActiveSync"` being returned for `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` property of a message store to identify it as an ActiveSync Exchange Message store. This message store is displayed as `Outlook E-Mail` on the device UI. This is true for **6.1** and **6.5** devices at least. I **did not** test on *Windows 7 phone*, as that is not the target audience for my app[2].

Hope this helps anyone doing similar stuff.

**[1]** Devices that I tested were from different Vendors(HTC, LG, Samsung), so I'm pretty confident this should hold true for obscure devices running Windows Mobile 6.1 or 6.5 OS.
**[2]** Please feel free to add info about Windows 7 phones, if you have one or have access to one. (I'm not sure if they still have MAPI still on those phones).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Windows Mobile, but why can't you check the PR_MDB_PROVIDER property?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had investigated this property, it is available on MS Outlook (Desktop), but not on Windows Phones.